# How set active region rightly in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to hightlight active region with nid=105. I did it in "color: feature.nid == 105 ? '#fa9f1a' : 'white'". But I have a problem, when I clicked to another region, region with nid=105 hightlight too. How to reset style for active region in my case?

```js
var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 308, "id":"POL","properties":{"name":"Poland"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[15.016996,51.106674],[14.607098,51.745188],[14.685026,52.089947],[14.4376,52.62485],[14.074521,52.981263],[14.353315,53.248171],[14.119686,53.757029],[14.8029,54.050706],[16.363477,54.513159],[17.622832,54.851536],[18.620859,54.682606],[18.696255,54.438719],[19.66064,54.426084],[20.892245,54.312525],[22.731099,54.327537],[23.243987,54.220567],[23.484128,53.912498],[23.527536,53.470122],[23.804935,53.089731],[23.799199,52.691099],[23.199494,52.486977],[23.508002,52.023647],[23.527071,51.578454],[24.029986,50.705407],[23.922757,50.424881],[23.426508,50.308506],[22.51845,49.476774],[22.776419,49.027395],[22.558138,49.085738],[21.607808,49.470107],[20.887955,49.328772],[20.415839,49.431453],[19.825023,49.217125],[19.320713,49.571574],[18.909575,49.435846],[18.853144,49.49623],[18.392914,49.988629],[17.649445,50.049038],[17.554567,50.362146],[16.868769,50.473974],[16.719476,50.215747],[16.176253,50.422607],[16.238627,50.697733],[15.490972,50.78473],[15.016996,51.106674]]]}},
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 309, "id":"PRT","properties":{"name":"Portugal"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-9.034818,41.880571],[-8.671946,42.134689],[-8.263857,42.280469],[-8.013175,41.790886],[-7.422513,41.792075],[-7.251309,41.918346],[-6.668606,41.883387],[-6.389088,41.381815],[-6.851127,41.111083],[-6.86402,40.330872],[-7.026413,40.184524],[-7.066592,39.711892],[-7.498632,39.629571],[-7.098037,39.030073],[-7.374092,38.373059],[-7.029281,38.075764],[-7.166508,37.803894],[-7.537105,37.428904],[-7.453726,37.097788],[-7.855613,36.838269],[-8.382816,36.97888],[-8.898857,36.868809],[-8.746101,37.651346],[-8.839998,38.266243],[-9.287464,38.358486],[-9.526571,38.737429],[-9.446989,39.392066],[-9.048305,39.755093],[-8.977353,40.159306],[-8.768684,40.760639],[-8.790853,41.184334],[-8.990789,41.543459],[-9.034818,41.880571]]]}},
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 310, "id":"ROU","properties":{"name":"Romania"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[22.710531,47.882194],[23.142236,48.096341],[23.760958,47.985598],[24.402056,47.981878],[24.866317,47.737526],[25.207743,47.891056],[25.945941,47.987149],[26.19745,48.220881],[26.619337,48.220726],[26.924176,48.123264],[27.233873,47.826771],[27.551166,47.405117],[28.12803,46.810476],[28.160018,46.371563],[28.054443,45.944586],[28.233554,45.488283],[28.679779,45.304031],[29.149725,45.464925],[29.603289,45.293308],[29.626543,45.035391],[29.141612,44.82021],[28.837858,44.913874],[28.558081,43.707462],[27.970107,43.812468],[27.2424,44.175986],[26.065159,43.943494],[25.569272,43.688445],[24.100679,43.741051],[23.332302,43.897011],[22.944832,43.823785],[22.65715,44.234923],[22.474008,44.409228],[22.705726,44.578003],[22.459022,44.702517],[22.145088,44.478422],[21.562023,44.768947],[21.483526,45.18117],[20.874313,45.416375],[20.762175,45.734573],[20.220192,46.127469],[21.021952,46.316088],[21.626515,46.994238],[22.099768,47.672439],[22.710531,47.882194]]]}},
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 105, "id":"RUS","properties":{"name":"Russia"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[143.648007,50.7476],[144.654148,48.976391],[143.173928,49.306551],[142.558668,47.861575],[143.533492,46.836728],[143.505277,46.137908],[142.747701,46.740765],[142.09203,45.966755],[141.906925,46.805929],[142.018443,47.780133],[141.904445,48.859189],[142.1358,49.615163],[142.179983,50.952342],[141.594076,51.935435],[141.682546,53.301966],[142.606934,53.762145],[142.209749,54.225476],[142.654786,54.365881],[142.914616,53.704578],[143.260848,52.74076],[143.235268,51.75666],[143.648007,50.7476]]],[[[22.731099,54.327537],[20.892245,54.312525],[19.66064,54.426084],[19.888481,54.86616],[21.268449,55.190482],[22.315724,55.015299],[22.757764,54.856574],[22.651052,54.582741],[22.731099,54.327537]]],[[[-175.01425,66.58435],[-174.33983,66.33556],[-174.57182,67.06219],[-171.85731,66.91308],[-169.89958,65.97724],[-170.89107,65.54139],[-172.53025,65.43791],[-172.555,64.46079],[-172.95533,64.25269],[-173.89184,64.2826],[-174.65392,64.63125],[-175.98353,64.92288],[-176.20716,65.35667],[-177.22266,65.52024],[-178.35993,65.39052],[-178.90332,65.74044],[-178.68611,66.11211],[-179.88377,65.87456],[-179.43268,65.40411],[-180,64.979709],[-180,68.963636],[-177.55,68.2],[-174.92825,67.20589],[-175.01425,66.58435]]],[[[180,70.832199],[178.903425,70.78114],[178.7253,71.0988],[180,71.515714],[180,70.832199]]],[[[-178.69378,70.89302],[-180,70.832199],[-180,71.515714],[-179.871875,71.55762],[-179.02433,71.55553],[-177.577945,71.26948],[-177.663575,71.13277],[-178.69378,70.89302]]],[[[143.60385,73.21244],[142.08763,73.20544],[140.038155,73.31692],[139.86312,73.36983],[140.81171,73.76506],[142.06207,73.85758],[143.48283,73.47525],[143.60385,73.21244]]],[[[150.73167,75.08406],[149.575925,74.68892],[147.977465,74.778355],[146.11919,75.17298],[146.358485,75.49682],[148.22223,75.345845],[150.73167,75.08406]]],[[[145.086285,75.562625],[144.3,74.82],[140.61381,74.84768],[138.95544,74.61148],[136.97439,75.26167],[137.51176,75.94917],[138.831075,76.13676],[141.471615,76.09289],[145.086285,75.562625]]],[[[57.535693,70.720464],[56.944979,70.632743],[53.677375,70.762658],[53.412017,71.206662],[51.601895,71.474759],[51.455754,72.014881],[52.478275,72.229442],[52.444169,72.774731],[54.427614,73.627548],[53.50829,73.749814],[55.902459,74.627486],[55.631933,75.081412],[57.868644,75.60939],[61.170044,76.251883],[64.498368,76.439055],[66.210977,76.809782],[68.15706,76.939697],[68.852211,76.544811],[68.180573,76.233642],[64.637326,75.737755],[61.583508,75.260885],[58.477082,74.309056],[56.986786,73.333044],[55.419336,72.371268],[55.622838,71.540595],[57.535693,70.720464]]],[[[106.97013,76.97419],[107.24,76.48],[108.1538,76.72335],[111.07726,76.71],[113.33151,76.22224],[114.13417,75.84764],[113.88539,75.32779],[112.77918,75.03186],[110.15125,74.47673],[109.4,74.18],[110.64,74.04],[112.11919,73.78774],[113.01954,73.97693],[113.52958,73.33505],[113.96881,73.59488],[115.56782,73.75285],[118.77633,73.58772],[119.02,73.12],[123.20066,72.97122],[123.25777,73.73503],[125.38,73.56],[126.97644,73.56549],[128.59126,73.03871],[129.05157,72.39872],[128.46,71.98],[129.71599,71.19304],[131.28858,70.78699],[132.2535,71.8363],[133.85766,71.38642],[135.56193,71.65525],[137.49755,71.34763],[138.23409,71.62803],[139.86983,71.48783],[139.14791,72.41619],[140.46817,72.84941],[149.5,72.2],[150.35118,71.60643],[152.9689,70.84222],[157.00688,71.03141],[158.99779,70.86672],[159.83031,70.45324],[159.70866,69.72198],[160.94053,69.43728],[162.27907,69.64204],[164.05248,69.66823],[165.94037,69.47199],[167.83567,69.58269],[169.57763,68.6938],[170.81688,69.01363],[170.0082,69.65276],[170.45345,70.09703],[173.64391,69.81743],[175.72403,69.87725],[178.6,69.4],[180,68.963636],[180,64.979709],[179.99281,64.97433],[178.7072,64.53493],[177.41128,64.60821],[178.313,64.07593],[178.90825,63.25197],[179.37034,62.98262],[179.48636,62.56894],[179.22825,62.3041],[177.3643,62.5219],[174.56929,61.76915],[173.68013,61.65261],[172.15,60.95],[170.6985,60.33618],[170.33085,59.88177],[168.90046,60.57355],[166.29498,59.78855],[165.84,60.16],[164.87674,59.7316],[163.53929,59.86871],[163.21711,59.21101],[162.01733,58.24328],[162.05297,57.83912],[163.19191,57.61503],[163.05794,56.15924],[162.12958,56.12219],[161.70146,55.28568],[162.11749,54.85514],[160.36877,54.34433],[160.02173,53.20257],[158.53094,52.95868],[158.23118,51.94269],[156.78979,51.01105],[156.42,51.7],[155.99182,53.15895],[155.43366,55.38103],[155.91442,56.76792],[156.75815,57.3647],[156.81035,57.83204],[158.36433,58.05575],[160.15064,59.31477],[161.87204,60.343],[163.66969,61.1409],[164.47355,62.55061],[163.25842,62.46627],[162.65791,61.6425],[160.12148,60.54423],[159.30232,61.77396],[156.72068,61.43442],[154.21806,59.75818],[155.04375,59.14495],[152.81185,58.88385],[151.26573,58.78089],[151.33815,59.50396],[149.78371,59.65573],[148.54481,59.16448],[145.48722,59.33637],[142.19782,59.03998],[138.95848,57.08805],[135.12619,54.72959],[136.70171,54.60355],[137.19342,53.97732],[138.1647,53.75501],[138.80463,54.25455],[139.90151,54.18968],[141.34531,53.08957],[141.37923,52.23877],[140.59742,51.23967],[140.51308,50.04553],[140.06193,48.44671],[138.55472,46.99965],[138.21971,46.30795],[136.86232,45.1435],[135.51535,43.989],[134.86939,43.39821],[133.53687,42.81147],[132.90627,42.79849],[132.27807,43.28456],[130.93587,42.55274],[130.78,42.22],[130.64,42.395],[130.633866,42.903015],[131.144688,42.92999],[131.288555,44.11152],[131.02519,44.96796],[131.883454,45.321162],[133.09712,45.14409],[133.769644,46.116927],[134.11235,47.21248],[134.50081,47.57845],[135.026311,48.47823],[133.373596,48.183442],[132.50669,47.78896],[130.98726,47.79013],[130.582293,48.729687],[129.397818,49.4406],[127.6574,49.76027],[127.287456,50.739797],[126.939157,51.353894],[126.564399,51.784255],[125.946349,52.792799],[125.068211,53.161045],[123.57147,53.4588],[122.245748,53.431726],[121.003085,53.251401],[120.177089,52.753886],[120.725789,52.516226],[120.7382,51.96411],[120.18208,51.64355],[119.27939,50.58292],[119.288461,50.142883],[117.879244,49.510983],[116.678801,49.888531],[115.485695,49.805177],[114.96211,50.140247],[114.362456,50.248303],[112.89774,49.543565],[111.581231,49.377968],[110.662011,49.130128],[109.402449,49.292961],[108.475167,49.282548],[107.868176,49.793705],[106.888804,50.274296],[105.886591,50.406019],[104.62158,50.27532],[103.676545,50.089966],[102.25589,50.51056],[102.06521,51.25991],[100.88948,51.516856],[99.981732,51.634006],[98.861491,52.047366],[97.82574,51.010995],[98.231762,50.422401],[97.25976,49.72605],[95.81402,49.97746],[94.815949,50.013433],[94.147566,50.480537],[93.10421,50.49529],[92.234712,50.802171],[90.713667,50.331812],[88.805567,49.470521],[87.751264,49.297198],[87.35997,49.214981],[86.829357,49.826675],[85.54127,49.692859],[85.11556,50.117303],[84.416377,50.3114],[83.935115,50.889246],[83.383004,51.069183],[81.945986,50.812196],[80.568447,51.388336],[80.03556,50.864751],[77.800916,53.404415],[76.525179,54.177003],[76.8911,54.490524],[74.38482,53.54685],[73.425679,53.48981],[73.508516,54.035617],[72.22415,54.376655],[71.180131,54.133285],[70.865267,55.169734],[69.068167,55.38525],[68.1691,54.970392],[65.66687,54.60125],[65.178534,54.354228],[61.4366,54.00625],[60.978066,53.664993],[61.699986,52.979996],[60.739993,52.719986],[60.927269,52.447548],[59.967534,51.96042],[61.588003,51.272659],[61.337424,50.79907],[59.932807,50.842194],[59.642282,50.545442],[58.36332,51.06364],[56.77798,51.04355],[55.71694,50.62171],[54.532878,51.02624],[52.328724,51.718652],[50.766648,51.692762],[48.702382,50.605128],[48.577841,49.87476],[47.54948,50.454698],[46.751596,49.356006],[47.043672,49.152039],[46.466446,48.394152],[47.31524,47.71585],[48.05725,47.74377],[48.694734,47.075628],[48.59325,46.56104],[49.10116,46.39933],[48.64541,45.80629],[47.67591,45.64149],[46.68201,44.6092],[47.59094,43.66016],[47.49252,42.98658],[48.58437,41.80888],[47.987283,41.405819],[47.815666,41.151416],[47.373315,41.219732],[46.686071,41.827137],[46.404951,41.860675],[45.7764,42.09244],[45.470279,42.502781],[44.537623,42.711993],[43.93121,42.55496],[43.75599,42.74083],[42.3944,43.2203],[40.92219,43.38215],[40.076965,43.553104],[39.955009,43.434998],[38.68,44.28],[37.53912,44.65721],[36.67546,45.24469],[37.40317,45.40451],[38.23295,46.24087],[37.67372,46.63657],[39.14767,47.04475],[39.1212,47.26336],[38.223538,47.10219],[38.255112,47.5464],[38.77057,47.82562],[39.738278,47.898937],[39.89562,48.23241],[39.67465,48.78382],[40.080789,49.30743],[40.06904,49.60105],[38.594988,49.926462],[38.010631,49.915662],[37.39346,50.383953],[36.626168,50.225591],[35.356116,50.577197],[35.37791,50.77394],[35.022183,51.207572],[34.224816,51.255993],[34.141978,51.566413],[34.391731,51.768882],[33.7527,52.335075],[32.715761,52.238465],[32.412058,52.288695],[32.15944,52.06125],[31.78597,52.10168],[31.540018,52.742052],[31.305201,53.073996],[31.49764,53.16743],[32.304519,53.132726],[32.693643,53.351421],[32.405599,53.618045],[31.731273,53.794029],[31.791424,53.974639],[31.384472,54.157056],[30.757534,54.811771],[30.971836,55.081548],[30.873909,55.550976],[29.896294,55.789463],[29.371572,55.670091],[29.229513,55.918344],[28.176709,56.16913],[27.855282,56.759326],[27.770016,57.244258],[27.288185,57.474528],[27.716686,57.791899],[27.42015,58.72457],[28.131699,59.300825],[27.98112,59.47537],[29.1177,60.02805],[28.07,60.50352],[30.211107,61.780028],[31.139991,62.357693],[31.516092,62.867687],[30.035872,63.552814],[30.444685,64.204453],[29.54443,64.948672],[30.21765,65.80598],[29.054589,66.944286],[29.977426,67.698297],[28.445944,68.364613],[28.59193,69.064777],[29.39955,69.15692],[31.10108,69.55811],[32.13272,69.90595],[33.77547,69.30142],[36.51396,69.06342],[40.29234,67.9324],[41.05987,67.45713],[41.12595,66.79158],[40.01583,66.26618],[38.38295,65.99953],[33.91871,66.75961],[33.18444,66.63253],[34.81477,65.90015],[34.878574,65.436213],[34.94391,64.41437],[36.23129,64.10945],[37.01273,63.84983],[37.14197,64.33471],[36.539579,64.76446],[37.17604,65.14322],[39.59345,64.52079],[40.4356,64.76446],[39.7626,65.49682],[42.09309,66.47623],[43.01604,66.41858],[43.94975,66.06908],[44.53226,66.75634],[43.69839,67.35245],[44.18795,67.95051],[43.45282,68.57079],[46.25,68.25],[46.82134,67.68997],[45.55517,67.56652],[45.56202,67.01005],[46.34915,66.66767],[47.89416,66.88455],[48.13876,67.52238],[50.22766,67.99867],[53.71743,68.85738],[54.47171,68.80815],[53.48582,68.20131],[54.72628,68.09702],[55.44268,68.43866],[57.31702,68.46628],[58.802,68.88082],[59.94142,68.27844],[61.07784,68.94069],[60.03,69.52],[60.55,69.85],[63.504,69.54739],[64.888115,69.234835],[68.51216,68.09233],[69.18068,68.61563],[68.16444,69.14436],[68.13522,69.35649],[66.93008,69.45461],[67.25976,69.92873],[66.72492,70.70889],[66.69466,71.02897],[68.54006,71.9345],[69.19636,72.84336],[69.94,73.04],[72.58754,72.77629],[72.79603,72.22006],[71.84811,71.40898],[72.47011,71.09019],[72.79188,70.39114],[72.5647,69.02085],[73.66787,68.4079],[73.2387,67.7404],[71.28,66.32],[72.42301,66.17267],[72.82077,66.53267],[73.92099,66.78946],[74.18651,67.28429],[75.052,67.76047],[74.46926,68.32899],[74.93584,68.98918],[73.84236,69.07146],[73.60187,69.62763],[74.3998,70.63175],[73.1011,71.44717],[74.89082,72.12119],[74.65926,72.83227],[75.15801,72.85497],[75.68351,72.30056],[75.28898,71.33556],[76.35911,71.15287],[75.90313,71.87401],[77.57665,72.26717],[79.65202,72.32011],[81.5,71.75],[80.61071,72.58285],[80.51109,73.6482],[82.25,73.85],[84.65526,73.80591],[86.8223,73.93688],[86.00956,74.45967],[87.16682,75.11643],[88.31571,75.14393],[90.26,75.64],[92.90058,75.77333],[93.23421,76.0472],[95.86,76.14],[96.67821,75.91548],[98.92254,76.44689],[100.75967,76.43028],[101.03532,76.86189],[101.99084,77.28754],[104.3516,77.69792],[106.06664,77.37389],[104.705,77.1274],[106.97013,76.97419]]],[[[105.07547,78.30689],[99.43814,77.921],[101.2649,79.23399],[102.08635,79.34641],[102.837815,79.28129],[105.37243,78.71334],[105.07547,78.30689]]],[[[51.136187,80.54728],[49.793685,80.415428],[48.894411,80.339567],[48.754937,80.175468],[47.586119,80.010181],[46.502826,80.247247],[47.072455,80.559424],[44.846958,80.58981],[46.799139,80.771918],[48.318477,80.78401],[48.522806,80.514569],[49.09719,80.753986],[50.039768,80.918885],[51.522933,80.699726],[51.136187,80.54728]]],[[[99.93976,78.88094],[97.75794,78.7562],[94.97259,79.044745],[93.31288,79.4265],[92.5454,80.14379],[91.18107,80.34146],[93.77766,81.0246],[95.940895,81.2504],[97.88385,80.746975],[100.186655,79.780135],[99.93976,78.88094]]]]}},
        ]};

        $(function(){
            var southWest = L.latLng(-85, -180),
            northEast = L.latLng(85, 180),
            bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            var map = L.map('map', {
                center: [27.25, 29.44],
                zoom: 2,
                maxBounds: bounds,
                minZoom: 2,
                scrollWheelZoom: false,
                doubleClickZoom: false,
                dragAndDrop: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                attributionControl: false,
            });

            var info = L.control();

            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

            info.update = function (props) {
            };

            info.addTo(map);

            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: feature.nid == 105 ? '#fa9f1a' : 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                };
            }

            function highlightFeature(e) {
                geojson.resetStyle()
                var layer = e.target;

                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 0,
                    color: '#fa9f1a',
                    dashArray: 1,
                });

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }

            var geojson;

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    click: highlightFeature
                });
            }

            geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);
        });
```

```css
body {
  background: #303030
}

#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting it's color separately finding it's layer like below

```
geojson.getLayers().find(ele => ele.feature.nid === 105).setStyle({ color: '#fa9f1a' });
```

```js
var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 308, "id":"POL","properties":{"name":"Poland"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[15.016996,51.106674],[14.607098,51.745188],[14.685026,52.089947],[14.4376,52.62485],[14.074521,52.981263],[14.353315,53.248171],[14.119686,53.757029],[14.8029,54.050706],[16.363477,54.513159],[17.622832,54.851536],[18.620859,54.682606],[18.696255,54.438719],[19.66064,54.426084],[20.892245,54.312525],[22.731099,54.327537],[23.243987,54.220567],[23.484128,53.912498],[23.527536,53.470122],[23.804935,53.089731],[23.799199,52.691099],[23.199494,52.486977],[23.508002,52.023647],[23.527071,51.578454],[24.029986,50.705407],[23.922757,50.424881],[23.426508,50.308506],[22.51845,49.476774],[22.776419,49.027395],[22.558138,49.085738],[21.607808,49.470107],[20.887955,49.328772],[20.415839,49.431453],[19.825023,49.217125],[19.320713,49.571574],[18.909575,49.435846],[18.853144,49.49623],[18.392914,49.988629],[17.649445,50.049038],[17.554567,50.362146],[16.868769,50.473974],[16.719476,50.215747],[16.176253,50.422607],[16.238627,50.697733],[15.490972,50.78473],[15.016996,51.106674]]]}},
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 309, "id":"PRT","properties":{"name":"Portugal"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-9.034818,41.880571],[-8.671946,42.134689],[-8.263857,42.280469],[-8.013175,41.790886],[-7.422513,41.792075],[-7.251309,41.918346],[-6.668606,41.883387],[-6.389088,41.381815],[-6.851127,41.111083],[-6.86402,40.330872],[-7.026413,40.184524],[-7.066592,39.711892],[-7.498632,39.629571],[-7.098037,39.030073],[-7.374092,38.373059],[-7.029281,38.075764],[-7.166508,37.803894],[-7.537105,37.428904],[-7.453726,37.097788],[-7.855613,36.838269],[-8.382816,36.97888],[-8.898857,36.868809],[-8.746101,37.651346],[-8.839998,38.266243],[-9.287464,38.358486],[-9.526571,38.737429],[-9.446989,39.392066],[-9.048305,39.755093],[-8.977353,40.159306],[-8.768684,40.760639],[-8.790853,41.184334],[-8.990789,41.543459],[-9.034818,41.880571]]]}},
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 310, "id":"ROU","properties":{"name":"Romania"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[22.710531,47.882194],[23.142236,48.096341],[23.760958,47.985598],[24.402056,47.981878],[24.866317,47.737526],[25.207743,47.891056],[25.945941,47.987149],[26.19745,48.220881],[26.619337,48.220726],[26.924176,48.123264],[27.233873,47.826771],[27.551166,47.405117],[28.12803,46.810476],[28.160018,46.371563],[28.054443,45.944586],[28.233554,45.488283],[28.679779,45.304031],[29.149725,45.464925],[29.603289,45.293308],[29.626543,45.035391],[29.141612,44.82021],[28.837858,44.913874],[28.558081,43.707462],[27.970107,43.812468],[27.2424,44.175986],[26.065159,43.943494],[25.569272,43.688445],[24.100679,43.741051],[23.332302,43.897011],[22.944832,43.823785],[22.65715,44.234923],[22.474008,44.409228],[22.705726,44.578003],[22.459022,44.702517],[22.145088,44.478422],[21.562023,44.768947],[21.483526,45.18117],[20.874313,45.416375],[20.762175,45.734573],[20.220192,46.127469],[21.021952,46.316088],[21.626515,46.994238],[22.099768,47.672439],[22.710531,47.882194]]]}},
            {"type":"Feature", "active": 1, "color": "#ffffff", "nid": 105, "id":"RUS","properties":{"name":"Russia"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[143.648007,50.7476],[144.654148,48.976391],[143.173928,49.306551],[142.558668,47.861575],[143.533492,46.836728],[143.505277,46.137908],[142.747701,46.740765],[142.09203,45.966755],[141.906925,46.805929],[142.018443,47.780133],[141.904445,48.859189],[142.1358,49.615163],[142.179983,50.952342],[141.594076,51.935435],[141.682546,53.301966],[142.606934,53.762145],[142.209749,54.225476],[142.654786,54.365881],[142.914616,53.704578],[143.260848,52.74076],[143.235268,51.75666],[143.648007,50.7476]]],[[[22.731099,54.327537],[20.892245,54.312525],[19.66064,54.426084],[19.888481,54.86616],[21.268449,55.190482],[22.315724,55.015299],[22.757764,54.856574],[22.651052,54.582741],[22.731099,54.327537]]],[[[-175.01425,66.58435],[-174.33983,66.33556],[-174.57182,67.06219],[-171.85731,66.91308],[-169.89958,65.97724],[-170.89107,65.54139],[-172.53025,65.43791],[-172.555,64.46079],[-172.95533,64.25269],[-173.89184,64.2826],[-174.65392,64.63125],[-175.98353,64.92288],[-176.20716,65.35667],[-177.22266,65.52024],[-178.35993,65.39052],[-178.90332,65.74044],[-178.68611,66.11211],[-179.88377,65.87456],[-179.43268,65.40411],[-180,64.979709],[-180,68.963636],[-177.55,68.2],[-174.92825,67.20589],[-175.01425,66.58435]]],[[[180,70.832199],[178.903425,70.78114],[178.7253,71.0988],[180,71.515714],[180,70.832199]]],[[[-178.69378,70.89302],[-180,70.832199],[-180,71.515714],[-179.871875,71.55762],[-179.02433,71.55553],[-177.577945,71.26948],[-177.663575,71.13277],[-178.69378,70.89302]]],[[[143.60385,73.21244],[142.08763,73.20544],[140.038155,73.31692],[139.86312,73.36983],[140.81171,73.76506],[142.06207,73.85758],[143.48283,73.47525],[143.60385,73.21244]]],[[[150.73167,75.08406],[149.575925,74.68892],[147.977465,74.778355],[146.11919,75.17298],[146.358485,75.49682],[148.22223,75.345845],[150.73167,75.08406]]],[[[145.086285,75.562625],[144.3,74.82],[140.61381,74.84768],[138.95544,74.61148],[136.97439,75.26167],[137.51176,75.94917],[138.831075,76.13676],[141.471615,76.09289],[145.086285,75.562625]]],[[[57.535693,70.720464],[56.944979,70.632743],[53.677375,70.762658],[53.412017,71.206662],[51.601895,71.474759],[51.455754,72.014881],[52.478275,72.229442],[52.444169,72.774731],[54.427614,73.627548],[53.50829,73.749814],[55.902459,74.627486],[55.631933,75.081412],[57.868644,75.60939],[61.170044,76.251883],[64.498368,76.439055],[66.210977,76.809782],[68.15706,76.939697],[68.852211,76.544811],[68.180573,76.233642],[64.637326,75.737755],[61.583508,75.260885],[58.477082,74.309056],[56.986786,73.333044],[55.419336,72.371268],[55.622838,71.540595],[57.535693,70.720464]]],[[[106.97013,76.97419],[107.24,76.48],[108.1538,76.72335],[111.07726,76.71],[113.33151,76.22224],[114.13417,75.84764],[113.88539,75.32779],[112.77918,75.03186],[110.15125,74.47673],[109.4,74.18],[110.64,74.04],[112.11919,73.78774],[113.01954,73.97693],[113.52958,73.33505],[113.96881,73.59488],[115.56782,73.75285],[118.77633,73.58772],[119.02,73.12],[123.20066,72.97122],[123.25777,73.73503],[125.38,73.56],[126.97644,73.56549],[128.59126,73.03871],[129.05157,72.39872],[128.46,71.98],[129.71599,71.19304],[131.28858,70.78699],[132.2535,71.8363],[133.85766,71.38642],[135.56193,71.65525],[137.49755,71.34763],[138.23409,71.62803],[139.86983,71.48783],[139.14791,72.41619],[140.46817,72.84941],[149.5,72.2],[150.35118,71.60643],[152.9689,70.84222],[157.00688,71.03141],[158.99779,70.86672],[159.83031,70.45324],[159.70866,69.72198],[160.94053,69.43728],[162.27907,69.64204],[164.05248,69.66823],[165.94037,69.47199],[167.83567,69.58269],[169.57763,68.6938],[170.81688,69.01363],[170.0082,69.65276],[170.45345,70.09703],[173.64391,69.81743],[175.72403,69.87725],[178.6,69.4],[180,68.963636],[180,64.979709],[179.99281,64.97433],[178.7072,64.53493],[177.41128,64.60821],[178.313,64.07593],[178.90825,63.25197],[179.37034,62.98262],[179.48636,62.56894],[179.22825,62.3041],[177.3643,62.5219],[174.56929,61.76915],[173.68013,61.65261],[172.15,60.95],[170.6985,60.33618],[170.33085,59.88177],[168.90046,60.57355],[166.29498,59.78855],[165.84,60.16],[164.87674,59.7316],[163.53929,59.86871],[163.21711,59.21101],[162.01733,58.24328],[162.05297,57.83912],[163.19191,57.61503],[163.05794,56.15924],[162.12958,56.12219],[161.70146,55.28568],[162.11749,54.85514],[160.36877,54.34433],[160.02173,53.20257],[158.53094,52.95868],[158.23118,51.94269],[156.78979,51.01105],[156.42,51.7],[155.99182,53.15895],[155.43366,55.38103],[155.91442,56.76792],[156.75815,57.3647],[156.81035,57.83204],[158.36433,58.05575],[160.15064,59.31477],[161.87204,60.343],[163.66969,61.1409],[164.47355,62.55061],[163.25842,62.46627],[162.65791,61.6425],[160.12148,60.54423],[159.30232,61.77396],[156.72068,61.43442],[154.21806,59.75818],[155.04375,59.14495],[152.81185,58.88385],[151.26573,58.78089],[151.33815,59.50396],[149.78371,59.65573],[148.54481,59.16448],[145.48722,59.33637],[142.19782,59.03998],[138.95848,57.08805],[135.12619,54.72959],[136.70171,54.60355],[137.19342,53.97732],[138.1647,53.75501],[138.80463,54.25455],[139.90151,54.18968],[141.34531,53.08957],[141.37923,52.23877],[140.59742,51.23967],[140.51308,50.04553],[140.06193,48.44671],[138.55472,46.99965],[138.21971,46.30795],[136.86232,45.1435],[135.51535,43.989],[134.86939,43.39821],[133.53687,42.81147],[132.90627,42.79849],[132.27807,43.28456],[130.93587,42.55274],[130.78,42.22],[130.64,42.395],[130.633866,42.903015],[131.144688,42.92999],[131.288555,44.11152],[131.02519,44.96796],[131.883454,45.321162],[133.09712,45.14409],[133.769644,46.116927],[134.11235,47.21248],[134.50081,47.57845],[135.026311,48.47823],[133.373596,48.183442],[132.50669,47.78896],[130.98726,47.79013],[130.582293,48.729687],[129.397818,49.4406],[127.6574,49.76027],[127.287456,50.739797],[126.939157,51.353894],[126.564399,51.784255],[125.946349,52.792799],[125.068211,53.161045],[123.57147,53.4588],[122.245748,53.431726],[121.003085,53.251401],[120.177089,52.753886],[120.725789,52.516226],[120.7382,51.96411],[120.18208,51.64355],[119.27939,50.58292],[119.288461,50.142883],[117.879244,49.510983],[116.678801,49.888531],[115.485695,49.805177],[114.96211,50.140247],[114.362456,50.248303],[112.89774,49.543565],[111.581231,49.377968],[110.662011,49.130128],[109.402449,49.292961],[108.475167,49.282548],[107.868176,49.793705],[106.888804,50.274296],[105.886591,50.406019],[104.62158,50.27532],[103.676545,50.089966],[102.25589,50.51056],[102.06521,51.25991],[100.88948,51.516856],[99.981732,51.634006],[98.861491,52.047366],[97.82574,51.010995],[98.231762,50.422401],[97.25976,49.72605],[95.81402,49.97746],[94.815949,50.013433],[94.147566,50.480537],[93.10421,50.49529],[92.234712,50.802171],[90.713667,50.331812],[88.805567,49.470521],[87.751264,49.297198],[87.35997,49.214981],[86.829357,49.826675],[85.54127,49.692859],[85.11556,50.117303],[84.416377,50.3114],[83.935115,50.889246],[83.383004,51.069183],[81.945986,50.812196],[80.568447,51.388336],[80.03556,50.864751],[77.800916,53.404415],[76.525179,54.177003],[76.8911,54.490524],[74.38482,53.54685],[73.425679,53.48981],[73.508516,54.035617],[72.22415,54.376655],[71.180131,54.133285],[70.865267,55.169734],[69.068167,55.38525],[68.1691,54.970392],[65.66687,54.60125],[65.178534,54.354228],[61.4366,54.00625],[60.978066,53.664993],[61.699986,52.979996],[60.739993,52.719986],[60.927269,52.447548],[59.967534,51.96042],[61.588003,51.272659],[61.337424,50.79907],[59.932807,50.842194],[59.642282,50.545442],[58.36332,51.06364],[56.77798,51.04355],[55.71694,50.62171],[54.532878,51.02624],[52.328724,51.718652],[50.766648,51.692762],[48.702382,50.605128],[48.577841,49.87476],[47.54948,50.454698],[46.751596,49.356006],[47.043672,49.152039],[46.466446,48.394152],[47.31524,47.71585],[48.05725,47.74377],[48.694734,47.075628],[48.59325,46.56104],[49.10116,46.39933],[48.64541,45.80629],[47.67591,45.64149],[46.68201,44.6092],[47.59094,43.66016],[47.49252,42.98658],[48.58437,41.80888],[47.987283,41.405819],[47.815666,41.151416],[47.373315,41.219732],[46.686071,41.827137],[46.404951,41.860675],[45.7764,42.09244],[45.470279,42.502781],[44.537623,42.711993],[43.93121,42.55496],[43.75599,42.74083],[42.3944,43.2203],[40.92219,43.38215],[40.076965,43.553104],[39.955009,43.434998],[38.68,44.28],[37.53912,44.65721],[36.67546,45.24469],[37.40317,45.40451],[38.23295,46.24087],[37.67372,46.63657],[39.14767,47.04475],[39.1212,47.26336],[38.223538,47.10219],[38.255112,47.5464],[38.77057,47.82562],[39.738278,47.898937],[39.89562,48.23241],[39.67465,48.78382],[40.080789,49.30743],[40.06904,49.60105],[38.594988,49.926462],[38.010631,49.915662],[37.39346,50.383953],[36.626168,50.225591],[35.356116,50.577197],[35.37791,50.77394],[35.022183,51.207572],[34.224816,51.255993],[34.141978,51.566413],[34.391731,51.768882],[33.7527,52.335075],[32.715761,52.238465],[32.412058,52.288695],[32.15944,52.06125],[31.78597,52.10168],[31.540018,52.742052],[31.305201,53.073996],[31.49764,53.16743],[32.304519,53.132726],[32.693643,53.351421],[32.405599,53.618045],[31.731273,53.794029],[31.791424,53.974639],[31.384472,54.157056],[30.757534,54.811771],[30.971836,55.081548],[30.873909,55.550976],[29.896294,55.789463],[29.371572,55.670091],[29.229513,55.918344],[28.176709,56.16913],[27.855282,56.759326],[27.770016,57.244258],[27.288185,57.474528],[27.716686,57.791899],[27.42015,58.72457],[28.131699,59.300825],[27.98112,59.47537],[29.1177,60.02805],[28.07,60.50352],[30.211107,61.780028],[31.139991,62.357693],[31.516092,62.867687],[30.035872,63.552814],[30.444685,64.204453],[29.54443,64.948672],[30.21765,65.80598],[29.054589,66.944286],[29.977426,67.698297],[28.445944,68.364613],[28.59193,69.064777],[29.39955,69.15692],[31.10108,69.55811],[32.13272,69.90595],[33.77547,69.30142],[36.51396,69.06342],[40.29234,67.9324],[41.05987,67.45713],[41.12595,66.79158],[40.01583,66.26618],[38.38295,65.99953],[33.91871,66.75961],[33.18444,66.63253],[34.81477,65.90015],[34.878574,65.436213],[34.94391,64.41437],[36.23129,64.10945],[37.01273,63.84983],[37.14197,64.33471],[36.539579,64.76446],[37.17604,65.14322],[39.59345,64.52079],[40.4356,64.76446],[39.7626,65.49682],[42.09309,66.47623],[43.01604,66.41858],[43.94975,66.06908],[44.53226,66.75634],[43.69839,67.35245],[44.18795,67.95051],[43.45282,68.57079],[46.25,68.25],[46.82134,67.68997],[45.55517,67.56652],[45.56202,67.01005],[46.34915,66.66767],[47.89416,66.88455],[48.13876,67.52238],[50.22766,67.99867],[53.71743,68.85738],[54.47171,68.80815],[53.48582,68.20131],[54.72628,68.09702],[55.44268,68.43866],[57.31702,68.46628],[58.802,68.88082],[59.94142,68.27844],[61.07784,68.94069],[60.03,69.52],[60.55,69.85],[63.504,69.54739],[64.888115,69.234835],[68.51216,68.09233],[69.18068,68.61563],[68.16444,69.14436],[68.13522,69.35649],[66.93008,69.45461],[67.25976,69.92873],[66.72492,70.70889],[66.69466,71.02897],[68.54006,71.9345],[69.19636,72.84336],[69.94,73.04],[72.58754,72.77629],[72.79603,72.22006],[71.84811,71.40898],[72.47011,71.09019],[72.79188,70.39114],[72.5647,69.02085],[73.66787,68.4079],[73.2387,67.7404],[71.28,66.32],[72.42301,66.17267],[72.82077,66.53267],[73.92099,66.78946],[74.18651,67.28429],[75.052,67.76047],[74.46926,68.32899],[74.93584,68.98918],[73.84236,69.07146],[73.60187,69.62763],[74.3998,70.63175],[73.1011,71.44717],[74.89082,72.12119],[74.65926,72.83227],[75.15801,72.85497],[75.68351,72.30056],[75.28898,71.33556],[76.35911,71.15287],[75.90313,71.87401],[77.57665,72.26717],[79.65202,72.32011],[81.5,71.75],[80.61071,72.58285],[80.51109,73.6482],[82.25,73.85],[84.65526,73.80591],[86.8223,73.93688],[86.00956,74.45967],[87.16682,75.11643],[88.31571,75.14393],[90.26,75.64],[92.90058,75.77333],[93.23421,76.0472],[95.86,76.14],[96.67821,75.91548],[98.92254,76.44689],[100.75967,76.43028],[101.03532,76.86189],[101.99084,77.28754],[104.3516,77.69792],[106.06664,77.37389],[104.705,77.1274],[106.97013,76.97419]]],[[[105.07547,78.30689],[99.43814,77.921],[101.2649,79.23399],[102.08635,79.34641],[102.837815,79.28129],[105.37243,78.71334],[105.07547,78.30689]]],[[[51.136187,80.54728],[49.793685,80.415428],[48.894411,80.339567],[48.754937,80.175468],[47.586119,80.010181],[46.502826,80.247247],[47.072455,80.559424],[44.846958,80.58981],[46.799139,80.771918],[48.318477,80.78401],[48.522806,80.514569],[49.09719,80.753986],[50.039768,80.918885],[51.522933,80.699726],[51.136187,80.54728]]],[[[99.93976,78.88094],[97.75794,78.7562],[94.97259,79.044745],[93.31288,79.4265],[92.5454,80.14379],[91.18107,80.34146],[93.77766,81.0246],[95.940895,81.2504],[97.88385,80.746975],[100.186655,79.780135],[99.93976,78.88094]]]]}},
        ]};

$(function() {
  var southWest = L.latLng(-85, -180),
    northEast = L.latLng(85, 180),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [27.25, 29.44],
    zoom: 2,
    maxBounds: bounds,
    minZoom: 2,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    dragAndDrop: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    attributionControl: false,
  });

  var info = L.control();

  info.onAdd = function(map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
  };

  info.update = function(props) {};

  info.addTo(map);

  function style(feature) {
    return {
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'white',
      dashArray: '3',
      fillOpacity: 1,
    };
  }
  
  const styles = {
      weight: 0,
      color: '#fa9f1a',
      dashArray: 1,
    };

  function highlightFeature(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle()
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle(styles);

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
      layer.bringToFront();
    }

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
  }

  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      click: highlightFeature
    });
  }

  var geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(map);
  geojson.getLayers().find(ele => ele.feature.nid === 105).setStyle(styles);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #303030
}

#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```